# How to find the number of elements in a set? CPLEX OPL

Tags: set, cplex, opl

Lets say I have a set:

```
{int} A ={1,2,3,4};
```

How can I get the number of elements in this set in CPLEX?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{int} A ={1,2,3,4};

int n=card(A);

execute
{
  writeln(n);
}
```

gives

```
4
```